# Return function in For loop in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df. I am trying to execute for loop to return the levels of all the factors. I have tried with the below code but not getting executed

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = structure(c(19L, 3L, 12L, 21L), .Label = c("asgfg", 
"dds", "dfg", "dfh", "dgh", "dghgd", "dgrert", "dgsh", "dsgdfg", 
"dsgdg", "e", "er", "ewt", "fdg", "fdgd", "fg", "gdfgd", "gdfsh", 
"gf", "gfdg", "gfs", "gh", "ghj", "ghjhg", "gjgj", "gt", "hdsger", 
"hgdhg", "hgj", "hjghj", "jgh", "jyfj", "ret", "rth", "ryuy", 
"sdf", "sdfh", "sfdg", "sgdf", "tyew", "tyu", "tyutyu", "uiuy", 
"yoiy", "yt"), class = "factor"), ColB = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), ColC = 1:4, 
  ColD = 2:5), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame"

sa <- names(Filter(is.factor,df))
for (i in sa)
{ res 
res[[i]] <= levels(factor(df[,i]))
return(res) }
```

I should get

```
res <- 
ColA = "dfg" "er"  "gf"  "gfs"

ColB = "A"
```

Comment: `lapply(df, levels)` or `purrr::map(df, levels)` if you like `purrr`. If you want it to work on any type of data (not only factors) you can do `lapply(df, unique)` but note the factor levels may not be shown in order when using `unique`. `lapply` applies a function (here `levels`) to all the elements of a list (a data frame is simply a list of columns) and return the results in a list. Internally it loops, but your code does not have to.

Comment: thanks. But not possible in for loop. I was interested in that :) ANyways your solution worked. But I am learning for loop so appreciate if you could help me in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is using a for loop.

```r
sa <- names(Filter(is.factor,df))

res <- list()

for (i in sa)
{
  res[[i]] <- levels(factor(df[,i]))
}
#res
#$ColA
#[1] "dfg" "er"  "gf"  "gfs"

#$ColB
#[1] "A"
```